# tkinter: grid method strange behavior

Tags: python, grid, tkinter, frames

I want this code to do this:

Create 4 frames with this layout (dashes mean the frame spans that column):

```
 -X-
 XXX
```

Within each of these frames (X's) there should be two rows like this:

```
cowN,1
cowN,2
```

It seems like the grid() method is *global* **ONLY** and is never specific to a single frame...

```
#!/usr/apps/Python/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(master).grid(row=0,columnspan=3)
frame2 = Frame(master).grid(row=1,column=0)
frame3 = Frame(master).grid(row=1,column=1)
frame4 = Frame(master).grid(row=1,column=2)
#->Frame1 contents
Label(frame1, text='cow1,1').grid(row=0)
Label(frame1, text='cow1,2').grid(row=1)
#->Frame2 contents
Label(frame2, text='cow2,1').grid(row=0)
Label(frame2, text='cow2,2').grid(row=1)
#->Frame3 contents
Label(frame3, text='cow3,1').grid(row=0)
Label(frame3, text='cow3,2').grid(row=1)
#->Frame4 contents
Label(frame4, text='cow4,1').grid(row=0)
Label(frame4, text='cow4,2').grid(row=1)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your are not keeping a reference to the `Frame` objects on your `frameN` variables:  you create the objects, and call their `grid` method: you store the return of the grid method on the variables, which is `None`.

So, your labels are being created with `None` as their master.

Just change your lines to read:

```
frame1 = Frame(master); 
frame1.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
```